# Error when trying to deploy Ethereum smart contract using web3j

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract in java using web3j and Ganache.
After the creation of the java wrapper for my contract, the code that I'm using to deploy the contract is:

```
public void deployGreeter(String pw, String walletFile, String _greeting) throws IOException, CipherException, Exception{
    Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(pw, walletFile);
    Greeter g = Greeter.deploy(web3, credentials, ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT, _greeting).send();

}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: 
buffer(okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource@10aa41f2).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 188] (through reference chain: org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthSendTransaction["error"]->org.web3j.protocol.core.Response$Error["data"])
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:302)
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$5(Contract.java:334)
at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)
at com.monsanto.ethereumtest1.Ganache.deployGreeter(Ganache.java:125)
at com.monsanto.ethereumtest1.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: buffer(okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource@10aa41f2).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 188] (through reference chain: org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthSendTransaction["error"]->org.web3j.protocol.core.Response$Error["data"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:60)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:101)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:101)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2908)
at org.web3j.protocol.Service.send(Service.java:33)
at org.web3j.protocol.core.Request.send(Request.java:71)
at org.web3j.tx.RawTransactionManager.signAndSend(RawTransactionManager.java:107)
at org.web3j.tx.RawTransactionManager.sendTransaction(RawTransactionManager.java:91)
at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:49)
at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:83)
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:242)
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.create(Contract.java:271)
at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:300)
... 4 more
```

I've also tried to deploy another contract, but the error output is the same.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The error seems to indicate there's an issue with your credentials. As a test, try hardcoding your private key into your `Credentials` object instead of reading it from the encrypted file. Replace your `Credentials` line with `Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(rawPrivateKey);` and try running it again. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Thank you Adam. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion of [Adam Kippis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8474917/adam-kipnis), I managed to deploy the contract creating a new credential based on the Credentials.create method.

Please see bellow the code that worked for me:

```
public String deployContract(String privateKey, String _lotNumber, int _weight) throws Exception{
    BigInteger biWeight = BigInteger.valueOf(_weight);
    Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey);
    cst = CST.deploy(web3, credentials, ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT, _lotNumber, biWeight).send();
    String ca = cst.getContractAddress();

    System.out.println("Contract deployed! Address: " + ca);
    return ca;
}
```

Thank you.